# "Expected an Indented Block" Error, but there is an indented Block

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting a Syntax "Expected an Indented Block" Error, but there is definitely an indented block there. I've checked and rewritten it a million times.

```
#Game loop:
while True: #The error is occurring here
    load()
    #Main game loop:
    while game_over == False:
            load_stage()
    #Win screen and restart option:
    print('\n**********************************************')
    print ('Congratulations! You Won!')
    answer = input('Would you like to restart?\nIf so type \'restart\'.')
    if answer == 'restart':
        restart()
        save()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Try formatting everything with 4 spaces instead of tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try:**

```
#Game loop:
while True: #The error is occurring here
    load()
    #Main game loop:
    while game_over == False:
        load_stage()
    #Win screen and restart option:
    print('\n**********************************************')
    print ('Congratulations! You Won!')
    answer = input('Would you like to restart?\nIf so type \'restart\'.')
    if answer == 'restart':
        restart()
        save()
```

The Error arise'd due to inconsistency in indentation, meaning that your program didn't had a consistent indentation scheme. In general it is advised to use 4 space's (where space = single spacebar) to represent an indented block.

Inconsistency can also arise, if your program uses Tab and spaces interchangeably, for indentation.

Comment: The `else: pass` is completely unnecessary; if you don't have anything you want to put there, simply omit the `else:` part entirely.